# How to tame Visual Studio Code sidebar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I try to interact with vscode via my keyboard only.

I use `cmd+t` to open files and I always have to cmd+b to close the sidebar.  If I am using fileA with the sidebar closed and switch to fileB (`cmd+t` fileB), the sidebar reopens. In other words, it seems that the sidebar setting is file dependent.

That is not the behaviour I expected.  I would like to open/close the sidebar as needed via my command.  If I `cmd+b` to close the sidebar, I would expect it to switch off the sidebar until I cmd+b again (independently of the file that is open).

Is this the standard behaviour of the sidebar in VSCode?  Is it possible to change it?
Are there suggested settings.json files people share (similar to dotfiles)?

Comment: Mine doesn't seem to do this - I am on PC.  I am guessing you changed what CMD + T does because the for me, CTRL + T is the go to symbol shortcut (the default setting).  Either way, my sidebar seems to stay closed when opening other files.

Comment: The same happens with Cmd+P for me.

Comment: Ser `Explorer: Auto Reveal` to `false`.

Comment: I tried Auto Reveal = false in the settings.  I didn't notice any change. It makes me wonder if there is something wrong with my environment.  I even created a new settings.json but still... any time I open cmd+P a file ... the sidebar opens too.